# Android 2.3 vs 2.2.1 Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, motorola

Can anyone tell me if there have been any changes to the bluetooth functionality in the Android update?
I have an app which uses transmission and reception concurrently with a total of 5 connected devices and this works perfectly on a Motorola Droid2 with 2.2.1 but not on the ATRIX running 2.3

There may of course be a hardware element involved but I wanted to establish this first.

thanks in advance.

John

Answer (score 0):

Android [website](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3-highlights.html) says "updated BlueZ stack", but that's all. 
Did you check the logs, what are the errors you're getting?

<strike>Also, I guess you can try running different emulators with different versions of Android and see how that behaves.</strike>

Comment: No android emulator that I am aware of has Bluetooth enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that the bluetooth connection worked only on the second try - the first one almost always fails internally (IOException). And you don't have much time in between trials. This was on my 2.3.3 Sony phone. Logcat showed some messages that might imply an internal problem in bluez or with the bluez/java integration.

This problem did not manifest on a 2.2.x Samsung phone. Note that my program only uses *one* connection at a time.